# After re-install my fullnode (kept the btc and lnc data directories), previously ACTIVE ln channel stays Inactive

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, channels

Reset my Node and reinstalled ALL softwares including lnd and Thunderhub.
Now my bitcoin is running well, LND is running well.
Thunderhub is also OK. but my previous opened channel is not Active.
from lnd command, it shows not active.
in Thunderhub (a lnd UI), It shows “red dot” from “Channels”
waited for 3 days still no change.
What action should I take to bring it back active?

the other side is from ACINQ as peer. thanks

Comment: Check the logs?

Comment: @C-Otto checking my lnd.log and see no obvious errors.